# How do we restrict Labels in Jira to each project?

Tags: jira

I am using Jira Cloud for our projects (say A, B and C). I have labels for project A, say, AL1, AL2 and AL3.

When I am trying to add labels for issues in Project B, Labels from Project A (AL1 etc) show up as options, even though they may not be relevant. Due to the # of labels in each project, this is becoming cumbersome to use.

What settings do we need to configure in Jira to restrict issue labels to the Project Context?

Answer (score 0):

We cannot restrict a Label inside a particular project, it will be global. Instead

- Can create a custom field for handling the labels.

  Or
- Can use Components field. But we cannot create a component on the fly, it will be created in the settings.